# azure bot framework v4 vs v3

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I am a beginner and got some tutorial videos based upon Bot framework v3 and was trying to implement Rich Cards with QnAMaker.
I have created Knowledgebase using "QnA Maker GA" and Bot using v3 QnAMaker template in Azure Bot Service.
Now the questions:

1. Can we still create Bot using BF V3 and QnA Maker GA (I tried but getting error)?
2. will there be support for BF v3 from Microsoft in future?

Answer (score 1):

1. Because bot framework v4 is generally available, you cannot create an new Bot using v3 QnA Maker template.
2. Microsoft officially encourage you to build your bot using v4. The v3 support will be end.

I can't find a video tutorial for you but the samples below would help you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-qna?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards

Comment: Thanks Akiyoshi Tsuchida.

Comment: Could you accept my answer for the future users?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers to your questions:

***Can we still create Bot using BF V3 and QnA Maker GA (I tried but getting an error)?***

Microsoft strongly recommends you to use V4 SDK and .net Core for future usage considering the fact that all new feature updates that you or your client needs will be available in these upcoming versions. They don't talk about any future upgrades in v3.

You can still use the old bot creation template from other web sites and also the old bot emulator to get started in v3.

[Bot Framework Template for v3](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/tree/master/CSharp/Generator)

[Bot Emulator Github link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v3.5.37)

Additionally, v3 only has bug fixes as of now, no new features have been added for a pretty long time. To be precise 10 months as of 2.28.2019

Hence, We cannot expect to use v3 if you're looking to consume any new upcoming features in Bot framework. Also, Note that since v3 is not that concentrated now, the bug fixes are also comparatively slow.

***will there be support for BF v3 from Microsoft in the future?***

As mentioned above, there is active bug fixing updates, but since the team is small, it takes time to get things fixed and many of the bugs we are talking about does not exist in v4. **Hence it's a bad idea to go with v3 if you need to stay updated to the industry**.